# leaflet / omnivore - create function to display omnivore CSV markers by property value

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, jquery

there seem to be a number of questions out there but none have quite answered this for me.

How would one go about taking a custom set of values from a property like latitude, and then assign them to change the marker color for omnivore.CSV data based on that value. Is there a way of calling the pointtoLayers functions within an `onready` style section and pointing it to fill colors based on these value tiers?

```
function getColor(d) {
    return d > 42.2 ? '#800026' :
           d > 39  ? '#BD0026' :
           d > 30  ? '#E31A1C' :
                      '#FFEDA0'; }

var MarkerOptions = {
    radius: 8,
    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.latitude),
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8 };

window.data3 = omnivore.csv('File.csv')
        .on('ready', function(layer) {
            this.eachLayer(function(markeroptions) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to GIS SE!

Note that the Leaflet [omnivore plugin API](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore#api) lets you specify more arguments, including a 3rd argument which is an `L.GeoJSON` layer group that you have prepared before hand.

> `.csv(url, parser_options?, customLayer?)`

In particular, you can set its `onEachFeature` and/or `pointToLayer` option(s), so that when omnivore gets the data, it will go through these options.

See: [Passing values for a geojson filter in Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203084/passing-values-for-a-geojson-filter-in-leaflet/203169#203169)

And this [Leaflet omnivore example](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore#custom-layers):

```js
var customLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
  // http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-style
  style: function(feature) {
    return {
      color: '#f00'
    };
  }
});
// this can be any kind of omnivore layer
var runLayer = omnivore.kml('line.kml', null, customLayer)
```

Comment: Excellent lead, ended up finding what I needed from this, thank you!